# Excel Chart "Save as Picture" making dates into numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to save a picture of an excel chart (for use in distributions where it doesn't allow me to just copy and paste the chart). So I right click the chart I want to save, [click "save as picture"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH4vv.png), and it's much clearer than just doing a snip or alt-printscreen. The only problem is, the date axis (on the x axis) is [converting from "Jan-20" to 43831](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGod5.png), which is not distribution-friendly. Excel knows what 43831 is, but the casual observer won't. How do I format the cells so that it doesn't appear as a number series when I try to save as picture?

Here's a screencap of what I want:

[image]

Here's what I'm getting:
[image]

Comment: I didn't even realize Excel 2016 had this option on right-click. I have 2016, and my computer does not have that option, but rather, only paste-special as image. I only see "save as picture" within Powerpoint, not excel. Is that an add-on to your Excel?

Comment: I don't recall, it might have been the Analyze in Excel add-on that works between Power BI and Excel, but it might have been default in my version.

Comment: @GunterHerd, if I'm not wrong you wanna to save the CHART itself as an IMAGE!! If yse the most easiest is Copy the Chart & Pate it in Paint brush then save as PNG/JPEG/Bit Map. Another is Paste in Word file, and while Paste use Paste Special the hit Microsoft Office Graphic Object. Hope this works for U !!

Comment: @Isolated Save As Picture was added by Microsoft fairly recently, to Microsoft 365, not to Excel 2016 or 2019.

Comment: I just tried to repro the problem, but the saved image file has dates, not day numbers.